# VBA: Drop down list - get items before and after the selected item

Tags: excel, vba

I have a drop-down list in my sheet. When I make a selection, is it possible to get the items before and after the selected item in the list?

Example:

[image: My List]

In the above list-
If the user selects "Kylo", I want to get "Han" and "Leia".
If "Luke" is selected, I want to get "Leia".
And if "Darth" is selected, I want to get "Han".

Is this possible?

Cheers,
VJ

Comment: I think it is possible. You can use the "Row Source" property of the listbox to take all entries in the listbox as string, then you can create an array from that string using split function and finally do anything you want with the array.

Comment: However, the above is probably one of many similar solutions!

Comment: Thanks Blenikos. Like I mentioned below, I'm not using a combo box, it's actually an in-cell data validation (List). Any way this can be implemented for an in-cell drop-down list?

Comment: I hadn't understood that you had a drop down list inside cell with data validation. I thought it was a combo box. Anyway the answer from Slai is just perfect! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question does not have enough details for a good answer, but from what I understand you have the list of values in the range `#DataSheet!A2:A51` and the selected item in cell `A1` so something like:

```
 Dim r As Range, c As Range
 Set r = [#DataSheet!A2:A51]
 Set c = r.Find([A1])
 If Not c Is Nothing Then
    If c.Row > r.Row Then MsgBox "Before: " & c(0)
    If c.Row < r.Row + r.Rows.Count Then MsgBox "After: " & c(2)
 End If
```

Comment: this is perfect! I just tweaked it a little bit to suit my needs. Added "LookAt:=xlWhole" so that FIND looks at the whole cell. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
' rename "Combobox1" to the name of your control below
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Dim idx As Long

    With ComboBox1 
        idx = .ListIndex
        If idx = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Next item: " & .List(idx + 1, 0)
        ElseIf idx = .ListCount - 1 Then
            MsgBox "Previous item: " & .List(idx - 1, 0)
        Else
            MsgBox "Previous item: " & .List(idx - 1, 0) & Chr(13) & "Next item: " & .List(idx + 1, 0)
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Miqi180. But I'm not using a combo box, it's actually an in-cell data validation (List). Any way this can be implemented for an in-cell drop-down list?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up importing the range into an array and then find the items before and after. Simple code below. Any inputs are welcome. Thanks heaps!

```
Sub GetItemBeforeAfter ()
Dim aArray As Variant
Dim sItem As String
Dim iCounter As Integer
Dim iPosition As Integer
Dim sItemBefore As String
Dim sItemAfter As String
aArray = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("#DataSheet").Range("A2:A51").Value
sItem = "Death Star"
    With Application
        For iCounter = LBound(aArray, 1) To UBound(aArray, 1)
            iPosition = .Match(sItem, .Index(aArray, 0, iCounter), 0)
            If IsNumeric(iPosition) Then
                Select Case iPosition
                    Case LBound(aArray, 1)
                        sItemAfter = aArray(iPosition + 1, 1)
                        MsgBox "No Before!"
                        MsgBox "After: " & sItemAfter
                    Case UBound(aArray, 1)
                        sItemBefore = aArray(iPosition - 1, 1)
                        MsgBox "Before: " & sItemBefore
                        MsgBox "No After!"
                    Case Else
                        sItemBefore = aArray(iPosition - 1, 1)
                        sItemAfter = aArray(iPosition + 1, 1)
                        MsgBox "Before: " & sItemBefore
                        MsgBox "After: " & sItemAfter
                End Select
            Exit For
            Else
                MsgBox "Item Not Found"
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```